# AngularJs: Show name of the month given the month number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the month as a number (1,2,3,...) and would like to display the corresponding name.
How can I do this?

Is it possible to use  `{{ date_expression | date[:format] }}`

Comment: {{date_expression | date:'MMMM'}} should work just fine. It works for both Date objects and for strings.
Could you share a sample for 'date_expression'

Answer (score 46):

Please take a look at the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date. There you will see the desired format:

```
{{date_expression | date:'MMMM'}}
```

From the docs:

```
'MMMM': Month in year (January-December)
```

Comment: I tired it but I obtain only January

Comment: Isn't that what you requested?

Comment: I'm only getting January also, iterating over an array from 0 to 11. Is weird because the following plunker works perfectly:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XRX4z9NJCWBtgxbVnUCM?p=preview

Comment: Ok, I found what is happening. date:'MMMM' must be used with a Date object. So instead of an array of integers from 0 to 11, I had to do: [new Date(2014, 0),new Date(2014, 1),new Date(2014, 2), ...] and so on.

Answer (score 41):

If you have the month index, you could just create your own filter:

```
myApp.filter('monthName', [function() {
    return function (monthNumber) { //1 = January
        var monthNames = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
            'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];
        return monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
    }
}]);
```

Then in your template:

```
{{date_expression | monthName}}
```

Comment: Nice example of how angular does it

Comment: You should put the monthNames array inside the filter definition function, but outside of the returned function so it's only being built once. If someone is doing an ng-repeat or ng-class or something, that will be a non-trivial amount of overhead.

Comment: How would it be done if i need write the name of the month inside a controller?

Can i apply the filter somehow ? or how to apply a service to display the month name ? 

`var choosenMonth = $scope.formData.monthNumber;

$scope.headers = ['Done in '+choosenMonth+'', 'In work until '+choosenMonth+')'];`

Comment: You need to inject the `$filter` service to the controller and then you can use `$filter('filtername')(arg1,arg2);`, in this case `$filter('monthName')(chosenMonth)`

Comment: When using angular-locale, you can do the following:
`function ($locale) {
        return function (monthNumber) {
            return $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH[monthNumber - 1];
        }
    }`

Answer (score 4):

Format string can be composed of the following elements for months:

'MMMM': Month in year (January-December) - `{{D_V | date:'yyyy-MMMM-dd'}}`

'MMM': Month in year (Jan-Dec) - `{{D_V | date:'yyyy-MMM-dd'}}`

'MM': Month in year, padded (01-12) - `{{D_V | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}`

'M': Month in year (1-12) - `{{D_V | date:'yyyy-M-dd'}}`

Know more at [Angular JS Date Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 2):

I am to understand you have the month as an integer value and not a date object. The date filter only works with formatted datetime or millisecond as strings, milliseconds as integer, or a `Date` object.

So you'd need to convert that month integer value to something the filter understands. You can take the month integer value and make it zero-indexed and then create a new dummy `Date` object from it, then apply the filter against that `Date`.

Controller:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
      // here's the original value
      $scope.month = 0; // 0 for january, 11 for december

      // watch for changes to the value of month. turn it into a new date object that angular can bind and filter in the view
      $scope.$watch('month', function(val) {
        // note: if you are expecting the month value to be one-indexed, you'll need to subtract 1 from val to make it zero-indexed as Date expects
        $scope.date = new Date(2014, val);
      });
    });
```

View:

```
{{ date | date:'MMMM' }}
```

[See this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XRX4z9NJCWBtgxbVnUCM?p=preview).

Another option is to use the `$filter` service directly, if you need a more direct way of converting the value. You're doing basically the same thing, just formatting the value in the controller rather than in the view.

Controller:

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
      // here's the original value
      $scope.month = 0;

      // watch for changes to the value of month, and then format it directly
      $scope.$watch('month', function(val) {
        $scope.date = $filter('date')(new Date(2014, val), 'MMMM');
      });
    });
```

View:

```
{{ date }}
```

[Alternate example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hx8eeXozbPIkYmoxdIxm?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. The problem is simple. We should convert the mysql date time to javascript date time then only you can format it in javascript.

so my format is:2008-04-25 00:00:00

```
  app.filter('format', function () {
          return function (item) {
               var t = item.split(/[- :]/);
           var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
           var time=d.getTime();                 
                   return time;
          };
        });
```

I have converted the mysql to javascript and then to millisecond then applied my filter its working.This may be not efficient. Its working in great manner. Hope this helps someone.

so my html:

```
<li  ng-repeat="x in names">
                <div class="date">
                <span class="day">{{ x.created_at | format | date:'d'}}</span>
                <span class="month">{{ x.created_at | format | date:'MMM'}}</span>
                </div>
                <p><a href="#">{{ x.study_description | makeUppercase}}</a></p>
            </li>
```

Its working fine. @Nishanth answer is giving me undefined. I have upvoted it since its seems working fine for some people. The date format support vary on browser tools too.

Answer (score 2):

Truly, the simplest method is combination of two other answers posted here. Using filter in a filter to obtain conversion and display month name in current language set:

```
app.filter('monthname',['$filter',function($filter){
    return function(month) {
      return $filter("date")(new Date(0,month),'MMMM');
    }
}]);
```

Now you can use this way `{{ 3 | monthname }}`

Note that without this, the original filter `{{ 3 | date:'MMMM' }}` will not work as it expects `Date` type as the argument, and not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Use MM to get the month in numeric

```
{{message.end_date | date : "dd-MM-y"}}
```

This will give you the result as 12-01-2017

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', 'lodash', function($scope, $filter, _) {
    $scope.monthNames = _.range(12).map(function(m) {
        return $filter("date")(new Date(0, m), 'MMMM'); }); 
    }]);
```

I'm using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#range) to get the range of numbers from 0 to 11, but you can easily get that list some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Peeking into the source code of the date filter within Angular's filters.js, I noticed that Angular stores the list of months in `$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH`. You can use it to make a very efficient filter:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []); 

app.filter("month", function($locale) {
    return function(month) {
        return $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH[month];
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <p ng-repeat="num in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">
       <span ng-bind="$index + 1"></span>: 
       <span ng-bind="$index | month"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Or forgo the filter and put it in the controller instead:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []); 

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $locale) {
    $scope.months = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <p ng-repeat="num in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">
       <span ng-bind="$index + 1"></span>: 
       <span ng-bind="months[$index]"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Or even as a directive. It may be overkill, but the html sure looks pretty (to me):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("month", function($locale) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($scope, elem, atrs) {
            $scope.$watch(atrs.month, function(month) {
                elem.text($locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH[month]);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <p ng-repeat="num in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">
       <span ng-bind="$index + 1"></span>: 
       <span month="$index"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```